# Creating a socket.io server for https connections

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openssl

I have done instructions from this page: https://medium.com/@invingagan/an-express-https-server-with-a-self-signed-certificate-and-socket-io-42d1f02d4d1a

That is, I created a self signed certificate:

```
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.cert
```

Then I use this server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static('public'));

const server = require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
},
    app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(1437, function () {
    console.log('https and websocket listening on *:1437');
});
```

However, when I try to connect using socket.io client, I got this error:

```
index.js:83 GET https://localhost:1437/socket.io/?framespersecond=15&audioBitrate=22050&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NJLEHQL net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

If I just copy and paste the URL in the browser URL field, I received the same error, so this is not a problem of socket.io client but the server miss to configure something.

I tried by creating a CA file and specify it in the call to `createServer` but it did not work either.

Any help?

Jaime

Comment: I think you have to configured socket io with express not? '`const ios = require(‘socket.io’)(secureServer);` seems like you're missing this from the tutorial.

Comment: @AvivLo sorry, I didn't know that code was important so I did not add it to the question. I already have this: var io = require('socket.io')(server); however, it is used only in io.on('connection', function (socket) { }. I don't think this has anything to do with the certificate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out there was a problem when generating the certificate using openssl.

I don't really know what happened, but since I have an already issued a self signed certificate (the one that is used by Visual Studio when developing sites to be debugged using IISEXPRESS), I have exported that certificate using Digicert utility and I could finally connect using socket.io.

Regards
Jaime